# angular2 add items dependig on selected value

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

Hi guys I'm quite new in Angular2 and Ionic2.
I'm trying to use at best all their features.

I would like to dynamically populate a div depending on the value of the select before the div itself.

this would be the html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Num of trips</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tripNum" (ngModelChange)="doTrips()">
    <ion-option value="1">1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">2</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="3">3</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
  <ng-container *ngIf="tripNum"> //?? not sure about what in here.. 
    <div *ngFor="let trip of trips">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Trip {{trip}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ion-item>
```

I've created an interface Trips, declared as trips:Trips[]

```
export interface Trips {
  duration : string;
  nofservices : number;
}
```

The "doTrips()" function should add as many Trips to the trips[] array depending on the tripNum. Then in my mind the *ngfor should add as many items as the trips array contains, and eventually bind the trip properties to the html thru [(ngModel)].

Hope the question is clear.. I'm  a little confused on what to use

Comment: What is this `legnum`?

Comment: it was the old name, the right one is tripNum, that is the selected value in the ion-select

Comment: Okay :) Could you please add the function `doTrips` to your question and I'll take a look at your code :)

Comment: what is legs and legsnum ?

Comment: I dont know where to begin.. I'd suppose something like doTrips(){ this.trips = []; for (let i of this.tripNum) { this.trips.push({duration:"",nofservices:0}); i++}} but I dont know how dynamically let it add to the dom and bind to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using `ngModelChange`, so there is no need for two-way binding. `[(ngModel)]` is short for `[ngModel]="tripNum" (ngModelChange)="doTrips($event)"`, so you can use that instead.

Also you need to move the `ng-container` outside of  `ion-item` for your code to work. So your template would look like this:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Num of trips</ion-label>
  <ion-select [ngModel]="tripNum" (ngModelChange)="doTrips($event)">
    <ion-option value="1">1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">2</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="3">3</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>


<ng-container *ngIf="tripNum"> 
  <div *ngFor="let trip of trips">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Trip </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

You `doTrips`-function would look like this:

```ts
doTrips(tripNum: number) {
  // declare obj of type Trips
  let obj = <Trips>{}
  // loop to add number of objects based on the value of tripNum
  for(let i= 1; i<=tripNum; i++) {
    this.trips.push(obj);
  }
  this.tripNum = tripNum;
}
```

Now we have to keep in mind, that each object added, is just an empty object of type `Trips`, so there are actually no values to show in the template. But you can assign value in the `doTrips` function if you want/need.

Finally a [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/COd2DuKFtldpSr1M0sGw?p=preview).

---

**Update:**

Now I see from comment that you want to add default value to `nofservices`, so your function would then look like this:

```ts
doTrips(tripNum: number) {
  // loop to add number of objects based on the value of tripNum
  for(let i= 1; i<=tripNum; i++) {
    this.trips.push(<Trips>{duration:'',nofservices:0});
  }
  this.tripNum = tripNum;
}
```

Note that you need to add the property name in your template for your `trip`, like so:

```ts
<ion-label>Trip {{trip.nofservices}}</ion-label>
```

Comment: Haven't tried it so far but it should be what I'm looking for..
Actually, inside ngcontainer I would like to put more select to populate the values of Trips[] (that's the doubt about data binding, I need to bind each item coming from *ngfor to each object of Trips[].

Comment: Not really understanding now what you are looking for... and there was no mention of that in your question..

Comment: I have to work on it a little to get to the point where I'll get stuck again eheh